# Codeigniter - Why Is My Email Going to The Spam Folder? How To Improve Email Delivery

Tags: codeigniter, email, spam

I am using codeigniter to send emails.Emails are sent on some interval to different users from same email address.
My issue is this emails are going to Spam folder instead of their Inbox.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about email deliverability, not about programming.  See further http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how are you actually sending emails, but it's very likely that you're not using some dedicated services.

Usually sending emails with *mail* or your gmail *SMTP* is ok for tests.

When things become bigger, it's really easy to be marked as spam.

There are many services for e-mail sending, like Mandrill and Mailgun. All you have to do is to find the right one for your needs and install the related package.

Hope it was useful.

Links:

- https://www.mandrill.com
- http://www.mailgun.com

Answer (score 0):

Using mandrill might help reduce spam. But still there are more issues to consider in your email content design, like the following:
1) embedded images instead of linked images
2) Links being hosted on your own domain rather than external websites.
3) Sometimes even the text used in the email content, can determine spam vs no spam. Tools like litmus.com help you test your email content, and show how likely it is that your email might end up in spam.

Hope this helps,